# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "0" at path "_id"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am starting to build my REST Api using Node.js for my web app. So far I tested it in postman and it works. For example I insert this link *http://localhost:3000/news* and works by giving me back a json response.

```
            [
          {
            "_id": "593978f7995e071df49b08d8",
            "updatedAt": "2017-06-08T16:19:03.551Z",
            "createdAt": "2017-06-08T16:19:03.551Z",
            "title": "Camping in the City and this year.",
            "image": "img/news1.jpg",
            "description": "From the Municipality of Larissa, and in particular the Social Policy Advocacy and the Department of Sports and Culture and Social Policy, it is announced that following the absolutely successful 'Camping in the City' program, organized last summer, the Municipality of Larissa in collaboration with the citys stakeholders, the program Will be implemented this year as well.",
            "__v": 0,
            "comments": [
              {
                "updatedAt": "2017-06-08T16:19:03.547Z",
                "createdAt": "2017-06-08T16:19:03.547Z",
                "rating": 5,
                "comment": "Λατρεύω το camping!!!",
                "author": "Theo",
                "_id": "593978f7995e071df49b08db"
              },
              {
                "updatedAt": "2017-06-08T16:19:03.550Z",
                "createdAt": "2017-06-08T16:19:03.550Z",
                "rating": 5,
                "comment": "Καλά μιλάμε τέλειο!!!",
                "author": "Chris",
                "_id": "593978f7995e071df49b08da"
              },
              {
                "updatedAt": "2017-06-08T16:19:03.550Z",
                "createdAt": "2017-06-08T16:19:03.550Z",
                "rating": 2,
                "comment": "Βαρετό.",
                "author": "Σοφία.",
                "_id": "593978f7995e071df49b08d9"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

My routes are written as shown

```
                    var express = require('express');
                var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
                var mongooser = require('mongoose');

                var News = require('../models/news')

                var newsRouter = express.Router();

                newsRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

                newsRouter.route('/')
                .get(function(req,res,next){
                    News.find({},function(err,news){
                       if(err) throw err;
                       res.json(news);    
                    });
                })

                .post(function(req,res,next){
                   News.create(req.body,function(err,news){
                      if(err) throw err;

                      console.log('News created')
                      var id = news._id;

                      res.writeHead(200,{
                         'Content-Type':'text/plain' 
                      }); 
                       res.end('Added the article with id: ' + id);
                   })
                })
                .delete(function (req, res, next) {
                        News.remove({}, function (err, resp) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            res.json(resp);
                        });
                });

                newsRouter.route('/:newsId')
                .get(function (req, res, next) {
                        News.findById(req.params.newsId, function (err, news) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            res.json(news);
                        });
                    })

                .put(function (req, res, next) {
                        News.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.newsId, {
                            $set: req.body
                        }, {
                            new: true
                        }, function (err, news) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            res.json(news);
                    });
                })

                .delete(function (req, res, next) {
                        News.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.newsId, function (err, resp) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            res.json(resp);
                    });
                });

                newsRouter.route('/:newsId/comments')
                    .get(function (req, res, next) {
                        News.findById(req.params.newsId, function (err, news) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            res.json(news.comments);
                        });
                    })

                    .post(function (req, res, next) {
                        News.findById(req.params.newsId, function (err, news) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            news.comments.push(req.body);
                            news.save(function (err, news) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                console.log('Updated Comments!');
                                res.json(news);
                            });
                        });
                    })

                    .delete(function (req, res, next) {
                        News.findById(req.params.newsId, function (err, news) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            for (var i = (news.comments.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                                news.comments.id(news.comments[i]._id).remove();
                            }
                            news.save(function (err, result) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                res.writeHead(200, {
                                    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                                });
                                res.end('Deleted all comments!');
                            });
                        });
                    });

                newsRouter.route('/:newsId/comments/:commentId')
                    .get(function (req, res, next) {
                        News.findById(req.params.newsId, function (err, news) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            res.json(news.comments.id(req.params.commentId));
                        });
                    })

                    .put(function (req, res, next) {
                        // We delete the existing commment and insert the updated
                        // comment as a new comment
                        News.findById(req.params.newsId, function (err, news) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            news.comments.id(req.params.commentId).remove();
                            news.comments.push(req.body);
                            news.save(function (err, news) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                console.log('Updated Comments!');
                                res.json(news);
                            });
                        });
                    })

                    .delete(function (req, res, next) {
                        News.findById(req.params.newsId, function (err, news) {
                            news.comments.id(req.params.commentId).remove();
                            news.save(function (err, resp) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                res.json(resp);
                            });
                        });
                    });

                module.exports = newsRouter;
```

Since this is ready,I want to read this json from the client side using Angular.js. So I created a factory.

```
angular.module('larissaApp')
               .constant('baseURL', 'http://localhost:3000/')
               .factory('newsFactory',['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource,baseURL) {

               var newsfac = {};

               newsfac.getNews = function(){
                    return $resource(baseURL+"news/:id",null,  {'update':{method:'PUT' }});
               };

               return newsfac;       

        }])
```

and a controller.

```
.controller('IndexController',['$scope','newsFactory','AnnouncementsFactory','EventsFactory',function($scope,newsFactory,AnnouncementsFactory,EventsFactory){

                 $scope.message="Loading ...";

                 $scope.newsOne = newsFactory.getNews().get({id:0})
                    .$promise.then(
                        function(response){
                            $scope.newsOne = response;

                        },
                        function(response) {
                            $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
                        }
                 );


                 $scope.newsTwo = newsFactory.getNews().get({id:1})
                    .$promise.then(
                        function(response){
                            $scope.newsTwo = response;
                            $scope.showDish = true;
                        },
                        function(response) {
                            $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
                        }
                 );


                 $scope.newsThree = newsFactory.getNews().get({id:2})
                    .$promise.then(
                        function(response){
                            $scope.newsTwo = response;

                        },
                        function(response) {
                            $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
                        }
                 );


                 $scope.eventOne = EventsFactory.getEvents(0);


                 $scope.eventTwo = EventsFactory.getEvents(1);


                 $scope.eventThree = EventsFactory.getEvents(2);



                 $scope.announcementOne = AnnouncementsFactory.getAnnouncement(0);
                 $scope.announcementTwo = AnnouncementsFactory.getAnnouncement(1);
                 $scope.announcementThree = AnnouncementsFactory.getAnnouncement(2);


    }])
```

As you can for now,I only read dynamically the news. However I get this error in console.

```
                events.js:160
                  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                  ^
            CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "0" at path "_id" for model "News"
                at MongooseError.CastError (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissa
            App\rest-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:26:11)
                at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaApp\rest-s
            erver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:149:13)
                at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-no
            de\larissaApp\rest-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1023:15)
                at ObjectId.castForQuery (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaAp
            p\rest-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:189:15)
                at cast (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaApp\rest-server\nod
            e_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:232:32)
                at Query.cast (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaApp\rest-serv
            er\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2933:12)
                at Query.findOne (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaApp\rest-s
            erver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1394:10)
                at Function.findOne (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaApp\res
            t-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:1360:13)
                at Function.findById (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaApp\re
            st-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:1288:15)
                at C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaApp\rest-server\routes\ne
            wsRouter.js:41:14
                at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-nod
            e\larissaApp\rest-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
                at next (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaApp\rest-server\nod
            e_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
                at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaApp\rest-
            server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
                at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-nod
            e\larissaApp\rest-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
                at C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaApp\rest-server\node_modu
            les\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
                at param (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\larissa-node\larissaApp\rest-server\no
            de_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
            npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
            npm ERR! errno 1
            npm ERR! rest-server@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
            npm ERR! Exit status 1
            npm ERR!
            npm ERR! Failed at the rest-server@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
            npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
            npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the rest-server package,
            npm ERR! not with npm itself.
            npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
            npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
            npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
            npm ERR!     npm bugs rest-server
            npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
            npm ERR!     npm owner ls rest-server
            npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

            npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
            npm ERR!     C:\Users\Theodosios\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-08T16_1
            9_28_708Z-debug.log
```

How can I fix this error? As I said everything works fine with postman.

Thanks,

Theo.

**Update**

I did a small change in my :/newsId route. Basically I converted req.params.newsId to a mongoose Type.

```
newsRouter.route('/:newsId')
                .get(function (req, res, next) {

                        News.findById(req.params.newsId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.newsId), function (err, news) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            res.json(news);
                            console.log(req.body._id);
                        });
                    })
```

But now I get this error.

```
2angular.js:12587 GET http://localhost:3000/news/0 500 (Internal Server 
Error)

index.html#!/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/news/0. No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:61612' is therefore not allowed access. The 
response had HTTP
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error a couples days ago, so here is my suggestion :

"0" is a string, so not an `ObjectId`, so you can try to turn it into one. Find the variable containing your id "0" and convert it into an `ObjectId` like that :

```
req.body._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id);
```

or

```
req.params.newsId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.newsId);
```

But you have another problem : 0 cannot be an `ObjectId` because an `ObjectId` must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters. So the above methods won't work. 
You may have not recieved a correct ID.

Hope it helps,

Best regards,

### UPDATE

You'r getting an error 500 because your update is wrong, you can't assign a value to `req.body._id` inside your method `News.findById`. You should do the following :

```
newsRouter.route('/:newsId')
  .get(function (req, res, next) {
    req.params.newsId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.newsId);
    News.findById(req.params.newsId, function (err, news) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(req.body._id);
      res.json(news);
    });
  });
```

Comment: This is what I do,but now I get back an empty array.  .get(function(req,res,next){
                        News.find({"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id)})
                            
                            .exec(function (err, news) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                res.json(news);
                            });
                    })

Comment: If you get an empty array, this means that mongo didn't find the `News` with your filter `{"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id)}`. Can you tell me what is the value in `req.body._id`

Comment: The news json array is stored in mongodb. I checked in my Node.js terminal with the command db.news.find().pretty();. Now req.body._id shows nothing. Here is what I did. .get(function(req,res,next){
                        
                        News.find({})
                            
                            .exec(function (err, news) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                res.json(news);console.log(req.body._id)
                            });
                    })

Comment: In fact in my console I get this: GET http://localhost:3000/news/0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: So that 0 id is wrong. Please check my controller as well.

Comment: I updated my answer, I'll come back in a few minutes

Comment: I really appreciate your time with me. I did that too,but I still get that one. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/news/0. No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I tried CORS.

Comment: This means that your server doesn't authorize your client to communicate with it. To solve that, you must write the following piece of code in your `app.js` (where you start your express app) : `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});`

It say that your server will accept requests from any origin (from any client).

Comment: That's good. I don't get this error anymore. Even if I get no error in the console though,I don't see in the browser my news objects(title,image,description). This is such a pain.lol.

Comment: I get this after a while. GET http://localhost:3000/news/0 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: The response from the server is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146200/discussion-between-boehm-s-and-theo).